# Find an example where the series does not converge for some x

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose the infinite series $\sum a_n$  is conditionally convergent.
Find an example such that the infinite series $\sum a_n\cos(nx)$ does not converge for some x.

My idea is to let $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $
And let $x = \pi$

However, im not sure how to continue.. Will appreciate if someone can help me! Thanks!

Comment: so what does $\cos(n\pi)$ equal to?

Comment: for even n, cos(nπ) =1
for odd n, cos(nπ) = -1

Comment: and for odd $n$, $\cos(n\pi)=-1$, right? then $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$

Comment: Where exactly do you need help? Checking the convergence of your guess?

Comment: Yes. I'm not really sure how to check the convergence!

Comment: Have you tried computing the first few terms? Does it remind you of any famous series?

Comment: How did you come up with this guess, incidentally?

Comment: Well... This $a_n$ is the only conditionally convergent series that I know of..

Comment: infinite series ∑ancos(nx) = the harmonic series?!?!

Answer (score 1):

well by your choice of $x=\pi$ and $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ we have $\sum a_n\cos(nx)=\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}(-1)^n = \sum \frac{1}{n}$, this is the harmonic series which is known to be divergent.

Comment: Yes yes thank you!! I just realized it a few minutes ago!